# JavaScript - Caesar Cipher

Tags: javascript, caesar-cipher

I know there have been a few posts about Caesar Ciphers in the past, which I have had a look at, but I haven't found an answer which has helped me to solve this kata, hence my post.

The language is JavaScript. I've written 3 tests, 2 of which are passing so far, but the third is not. I tried to use a nested for loop to loop over the alphabet and the str, and compare them, then shift the alphabet index up/down according to whatever the number was, then push that letter into a new array, and return the joined array at the end.

It's working for positive numbers, but not negatives. (I should also point out that I haven't thought of how to handle spaces yet, I just wanted to get it working for single words first, then take it from there, thanks!)

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

**Kata Instructions:**

The function caesarCipher should take a string and a number (n) and return a new string with a Caesar cipher applied. A Caesar cipher replaces each plaintext letter with a different one a fixed number of places up or down the alphabet. N represents the number of shifts up or down the alphabet should be applied. It may be negative or positive.

```
  E.g.
  caesarCipher('hello', 2)
    --> 'jgnnq'
  caesarCipher('hello world!', -3)
    --> 'ebiil tloia!'
```

My tests:

```js
const caesarCipher = require("../katas/caesar-cipher");
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe.only("caesarCipher", () => {
  it("returns an empty string when passed an empty string", () => {
    const alphabet = [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c",
      "d",
      "e",
      "f",
      "g",
      "h",
      "i",
      "j",
      "k",
      "l",
      "m",
      "n",
      "o",
      "p",
      "q",
      "r",
      "s",
      "t",
      "u",
      "v",
      "w",
      "x",
      "y",
      "z"
    ];
    const str = "";
    const num = 2;
    const actualResults = caesarCipher(alphabet, str, num);
    const expectedResults = "";
    expect(actualResults).to.equal(expectedResults);
  });
  it("returns a string with the letters replaced by the number of shifts up the alphabet", () => {
    const alphabet = [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c",
      "d",
      "e",
      "f",
      "g",
      "h",
      "i",
      "j",
      "k",
      "l",
      "m",
      "n",
      "o",
      "p",
      "q",
      "r",
      "s",
      "t",
      "u",
      "v",
      "w",
      "x",
      "y",
      "z"
    ];
    const str = "hi";
    const num = 2;
    const actualResults = caesarCipher(alphabet, str, num);
    const expectedResults = "jk";
    expect(actualResults).to.equal(expectedResults);
  });
  it("returns a string with the letters replaced by the number of shifts down the alphabet", () => {
    const alphabet = [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c",
      "d",
      "e",
      "f",
      "g",
      "h",
      "i",
      "j",
      "k",
      "l",
      "m",
      "n",
      "o",
      "p",
      "q",
      "r",
      "s",
      "t",
      "u",
      "v",
      "w",
      "x",
      "y",
      "z"
    ];
    const str = "dog";
    const num = -3;
    const actualResults = caesarCipher(alphabet, str, num);
    const expectedResults = "ald";
    expect(actualResults).to.equal(expectedResults);
  });
});
```

My Solution:

```js
function caesarCipher(alphabet, str, num) {
  const strToArray = str.split("");
  console.log(strToArray);
  const cipheredStr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < strToArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
      if (strToArray[i] === alphabet[j] && Math.sign(num) === 1) {
        console.log(Math.sign(num));
        cipheredStr.push(alphabet[(j += num)]);
      } else if (strToArray[i] === alphabet[j] && Math.sign(num) === -1) {
        console.log(Math.sign(num));
        console.log(alphabet[(j -= num)]);
        cipheredStr.push(alphabet[(j -= num)]);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(cipheredStr.join(""));
  return cipheredStr.join("");
}
```

The Results:

```js
caesarCipher
[]

    ✓ returns an empty string when passed an empty string
[ 'h', 'i' ]
1
1
jk
    ✓ returns a string with the letters replaced by the number of shifts up the alphabet
[ 'd', 'o', 'g' ]
-1
g
-1
r
-1
j
jum
    1) returns a string with the letters replaced by the number of shifts down the alphabet


  2 passing (15ms)
  1 failing

  1) caesarCipher
       returns a string with the letters replaced by the number of shifts down the alphabet:

      AssertionError: expected 'jum' to equal 'ald'
      + expected - actual

      -jum
      +ald
      
      at Context.<anonymous> (spec/caesar-cipher.spec.js:108:30)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

Comment: Hi @IndigoDreams, please, provide code source/snippets instead of images.

Comment: Has that worked ok? :)

Comment: The solution could be way simpler. I read the algorithm in wiki: charOutIndex = (charInIndex + num) % alphabet.length

Comment: So the trick is the modulo operator %

Comment: I've used the modulo operator before, but wouldn't have though to use it in this situation. I'll take a look into it, thanks :)

Comment: *"It's working for positive numbers, but not negatives"* are you aware that you can write every negative index as a positive one? for example: `-3` is the same rotation as `+23`

Comment: This fixes the JavaScript modulo bug which gives you negative result: https://web.archive.org/web/20090717035140if_/javascript.about.com/od/problemsolving/a/modulobug.htm

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when `num` is negative, you are doing the mapping:

```
cipheredStr.push(alphabet[(j -= num)]);
```

But `num` is negative. When you subtract a negative number what you are doing is adding its absolute value.

Instead, you should do:

```
cipheredStr.push(alphabet[j + num]);
```

Also, note that to compute the index in the alphabet you don't need to put the `=` in there.

---

**Side notes**

I understand that your solution is a work in progress. You have to take into consideration:

- What happens when you sum `j + num` to do the translation and it goes out of boundaries of your alphabet. Same thing could happen with a negative value of `num`.
- In the declaration of the problem, it states that `caesarCipher` should only accept two parameters, but you are passing the alphabet as first parameter!

Good luck with your code and keep trying :)

Comment: Ok, thanks, yes that's another thing that I've started to think about but haven't addressed yet. I was thinking i'd maybe just carry on looping back round the alphabet, so if the num took the letter beyond Z, then it'd just loop back round through A and vice versa, but haven't quite got that far yet. Thanks for the suggestions everyone! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
let arr = alphabets.split('')
// Cipher Get
function getCipher(str= alphabets, shift=3){
    return arr.reduce((a, c, i) => {
        let result = [...a]
        let tIndex = ( i + shift) % arr.length
        result[i]=arr[tIndex]
        return result;
    },[])
}

// Encrypt 
let stringToEnc = 'danger'
console.log('Plain Text -', stringToEnc)
let cipheredAlphabets = getCipher()
let encryptedStr = stringToEnc
    .toLowerCase()
    .split('')
    .map(function(p, i){
        let indexInAlphabets = arr.findIndex(c => p == c)
        return (cipheredAlphabets[indexInAlphabets])
    })
let encryptedText = encryptedStr.join('')
console.log('encrypted text - ', encryptedText)

// Decrypt
let cipherForDecrypt = getCipher(alphabets, -3)

let decryptedStr = encryptedText
    .toLowerCase()
    .split('')
    .map(function(p, i){
        let indexInAlphabets = cipheredAlphabets.findIndex(c => p == c)
        return (arr[indexInAlphabets])
    })
console.log('decrypted text - ', decryptedStr.join(''))
```